# How do I find Google Play version?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I am setting up gradle, I have to add something like:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1+'
```

I don't like to use the +, so I can always know which version the project is being compiled with and so I can avoid some surprise bugs.

In order to find the Google Play version I have currently downloaded, I usually go to the library XML file which I can find something like: "6171000", which is the version as an integer.

Is it there a simpler way to figure out the version that I need to write on gradle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `cd` into your module (eg: `app`) dir, and run gradle command line `..\gradlew -q dependencies --configuration compile`. This will resolve the `+` , and show you exact version being used for your library. See below.

[image]

- Or, if you use `Android Studio`, when you modify/edit the version (eg: simply delete/add `+` at the end),  Android Studio will show a yellow-bulb action with `Replace with specific version`, click on it to automatically replace the `+` with exact version available.

Comment: This website is outdated, current version is 6.1.71... but I liked the AS solution, although I would appreciate a way to find it myself, just in case AS changes in the future...

Answer (score 0):

Go to this site: http://gradleplease.appspot.com/#play-services

You can also search for any library (Ex. **recyclerview**). This will help you specify the library's latest version.

Comment: This website is outdated, current version is 6.1.71... I would like a more reliable solution